# Adding divs with a loop using jquery and setting div to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm curious about this behaviour. Why does this only create one `div`:

```js
let text = 'some text';
let $div = $('<div></div>');
$div.text(text);
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  $('article').append($div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article></article>
```

If I change the append to `("</div>" + text + '</div>');` then it creates five. It seems that the div is being overwritten in the loop, but shouldn't it be appending a new one each time? Why is it overwriting?

Comment: It's because `$div` is always a *reference* to the same, single `div` element. To append multiple elements you need to create a new `div` within the loop

Comment: You created 1 div and added to the DOM 5 times. If you add it in a different location every time, you'll notice you're only moving it, not cloning it. The second approach, with HTML string code, is actually interpreted as a new element. This is not a JQuery specific behaviour, but a DOM feature.

Comment: You will also notice that if you move lines 2 and 3 inside the for loop, you should get 5 as well, but that is because you are creating a new div referenced by $div for each loop then instead of the same div.

Comment: jQuery clone can help you create deep copy: [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: what about `$('article').append(\`<div>${text}</div>\`.repeat(5));`

Answer (score 0):

Like Rory mentioned, you're referencing the same `<div>` element that was created before the loop begins. To append a new one each time you can write:

```js
let text = 'some text';
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  $('article').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article></article>
```

jQuery's `append()` is very versatile, it accepts a :DOM element, text node, array of elements, HTML string, or a jQuery object. Details [here](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 0):

The instance of the `$div` that you create will be referenced as the **same object** in each iteration of the loop with `.append()`. Once created, looping through each time will just **access it again, replacing it with itself**, as though you had used a selector and content manipulation method to change it each time. You can see this if you include the iteration count in the text:

```js
let text = 'some text'
let $div = $('<div></div>')
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  $div.text(text + ' ' + x)
  $('article').append($div)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article></article>
```

To create a **new instance** of the object, you can use the jquery `.clone()` method to create a deep copy of it. This will create a new object each time.

```js
let text = 'some text'
let $div = $('<div></div>')
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  $div.text(text + ' ' + x)
  $('article').append($div.clone())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article></article>
```